# Android 11 (API30) Set 'All files' permission programmatically

Tags: android, permissions, storage

In Android 11 (API30), is there a way to enable the 'All files' permission programmatically?

> On the Settings > Privacy > Permission manager > Files and media page,
> each app that has the permission is listed under Allowed for all files

Tried with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but no luck.

Comment: Start an intent for `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`.